# JavaScript Object Function Access Variable in setTimeout

Tags: oop, recursion, settimeout

I am a newbie in OOP in JS. Right now I am trying to call variable in the instance, but how can I call it in the function?

```
var foo = function() {

    this.a = 1;    // how can I call 'a' in the setTimeout() function

    this.start = function(i) {
        if (i<3){
            window.setTimeout(function() {

                console.log(a);    // this line shows undefined
                console.log(this.a);      // this line indicates 'this' is window

                i++;
                start(i);    // this one does not work as well

            }, 2000);
        }
    };
};

var bar = new foo(); 
bar.start(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store `this` in a variable before the function:

```js
var foo = function() {

    this.a = 1;    // how can I call 'a' in the setTimeout() function

    this.start = function(i) {
        var that = this;
        if (i<3){
            window.setTimeout(function() {

                console.log(that.a);      

                i++;
                that.start(i);    // this one does not work as well

            }, 2000);
        }
    };
};

var bar = new foo(); 
bar.start(0);
```

Alternatively, you can use ES6's new [*arrow functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) depending on your project requirements:

```js
window.setTimeout(() => {

    console.log(this.a);      

    i++;
    this.start(i);    // this one does not work as well
}, 2000);
```